# Find text in array use preg_match

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I have code :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Time] => 05/24/2016 05:24
            [Type] => Income
            [Batch] => 134410438
            [Currency] => USD
            [Amount] => 60.00
            [Fee] => 0.00
            [Payer Account] => 123213
            [Payee Account] => 512321
            [Memo] => ,Received Payment 60.00 USD from account 123213. Memo: API Payment. EXCHANGE755531.
        )
```

How i can find text "EXCHANGE755531" in this array use preg_match ?

Comment: Look at the [examples](http://php.net/preg_match).

Comment: Is that format consistent `Memo: API Payment.`? Have you tried any regexs yet? You can try regexs here, https://regex101.com/, then bring it to PHP once you have it working. You should access the `Memo` index of that array to start with.

Comment: Is `EXCHANGExxxxx` always at the end?

Comment: You have not posted any code. Just data. Show us your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/(\w+)\.$/", $arr[0]["Memo"], $match);
Echo $match[1];
// This only works if the word is the last word before "."


preg_match("/Memo: API Payment\.\s+(\w+)/", $arr[0]["Memo"], $match);
Echo $match[1];
//this only works if "Memo: API Paayment." is static.


preg_match("/(EXCHANGE\d+)/",  $arr[0]["Memo"], $match);
// this one searches for the word "EXCHANGE" and digits after
```

Choose the one that suits you best.

Comment: Thanks you so much :)

Comment: How i can find in multi array ?

Comment: You mean like the array you mentioned? The code should do that. Or do you mean find as in search all records of the array?